# How to use 2 functions in an onBlur with ui material?

Tags: reactjs

I'm using the material ui library, and in the onBlur input event I'm adding 2 events, one that is coming by props and another is declared in the same component.

```
onBlur={(props.onBlur, validation)}
```

but he only recognizes me for the second event that happened to him.
It is not recognizing me the two events that are in onBlur.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import FormHelperText from "@material-ui/core/FormHelperText";
import Input from "@material-ui/core/Input";
import InputLabel from "@material-ui/core/InputLabel";

export default function CustomInputExample(props) {
  const [validationValue, setValidation] = useState(false);

  const validation = () => {
    if (props.value === "") setValidation(true);
    else setValidation(false);
  };
  return (
    <FormControl>
      <InputLabel htmlFor={props.name}>{props.labelText}</InputLabel>
      <Input
        name={props.name}
        aria-describedby="component-helper-text"
        type="text"
        onChange={props.onChange}
        onBlur={(props.onBlur, validation)}
        value={props.value}
      />
      {props.required !== undefined && validationValue ? (
        <FormHelperText id={props.name}>Required field</FormHelperText>
      ) : null}
    </FormControl>
  );
}
```

I need to use those two events in onBlur.

Comment: Hi Edward, check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call 2 function using an anonymous function,

```
onBlur={() => { 
    props.onBlur(); 
    validation();
}}
```